# Can we select the datas that have spaces between the lines in DB without the spaces?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a textbox to make a search in my table.My table name is ADDRESSBOOK and this table holds the personel records like name,surname,phone numbers and etc.The phone numbers holding like "0 123 456789".If I write "0 123 456789" in my textbox in the background this code is working

```
SELECT * FROM ADDRESSBOOK WHERE phonenumber LIKE "0 123 456789"
```

My problem is how can I select the same row with writing "0123456789" in the textbox.Sorry for my english

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replace()`:

```
WHERE REPLACE(phonenumber, ' ', '') LIKE REPLACE('0 123 456789', ' ', '')
```

If performance is an issue, you can do the following in SQL Server:

```
alter table t add column phonenumber_nospace as (replace(phonenumber, ' ', '');

create index idx_t_phonenumber_nospace on t(phonenumber_nospace);
```

Then, remove the spaces in the parameter value before constructing the query, and use:

```
WHERE phonenumber_nospace = @phonenumber_nospace
```

This assumes an equality comparison, as in your example.

Comment: Why not `=` instead of `LIKE`?

Comment: it's not help me because i'm writing 0123456789 not 0 123 456789.I need to select when I write 0123456789

Comment: @DarthMaul . . . So what?  The `replace()` is on both sides so spaces will be ignored.

Comment: @jarlh . . . The OP originally had `like`.  I assumed this was intentional so wildcards could be introduced.

Comment: `REPLACE(phonenumber, ' ', '')` is non-Sargable, so better to ensure number is stored consistently as per my answer. `REPLACE('0 123 456789', ' ', '')` is fine though to ensure the number is the same format if stored without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a specific format in which the Phone number is stored than you can insert space at the specific locations and than pass that to the database query.

For Example as you have mentioned in the question for number 0 123 456789.

If there is a space after first number and space after fourth number then you could take the text from the textbox and insert space at second position and sixth position(as after adding space at second position + next three positions are number so sixth position) and pass that text to the database query.

Answer (score 0):

An important part of Db design is ensuring data consistency. The more consistently it's stored, the easier it is to query. That's why you should make a point of ensuring your columns use the correct data types:

- Dates/time columns should use an appropriate date/time type.
- Number columns should use a numeric type of the appropriate size. (None of this numeric varchar rubbish.)
- String columns should be of the appropriate length (whether `char` or `varchar`).
- Columns with referential relationships should never store invalid references to the referenced table.

And similarly, you need to determine the exact format you wish to use when storing telephone numbers; and ensure that any time you store a number it's done so consistently.

Some queries will be complex enough as is. As soon as you're unable to rely on a consistent format, your queries to find data need to cater for all the possible variations. They'll be less likely to leverage indexes effectively.

> I have seen argument in favour of storing telephone numbers as *numeric* data. (It is after all a "number".) Though I'm not really convinced because this approach would be unable to represent leading zeroes (which might be desirable).

---

## Conclusion

Whenever you insert/update a telephone number, ensure it's stored in a consistent format. (NOTE: You can be flexible about how the number appears to your users. It's only the stored value that needs to be consistent.)

Whenever you search for a telephone number, convert the search value into the compatible format before searching.

It's up to you exactly where/how you do these conversions. But you might wish to consider `CHECK` constraints to ensure that if you failed to convert a number appropriately at some point, that it isn't accidentally stored in the incorrect format. E.g.

```
CONSTRAINT CK_NoSpacesInTelno CHECK (Telephone NOT LIKE '% %')
```